# why is it timing out like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tcp, proxy

I'm trying to build a TCP-proxy script that sends and receives data, i managed to get it to listen but it doesn't seem to be connecting properly...my code looks right to me and after checking python docs(i'm trying to run it in python 2.7 and 3.6) i get this timeout message:

Output:

```
anon@kali:~/Desktop/python scripts$ sudo python TCP\ proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.target.ca 21 True
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:21d
[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:44806d
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "TCP proxy.py", line 60, in proxy_handler
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host,remote_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

i looked into the file "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py" but couldn't really understand what i was looking for as it seemed right when i compared it to python docs and my script

my code:

```
# import the modules
import sys
import socket
import threading

#define the server
def server_loop(local_host,local_port,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        server.bind((local_host, local_port))
        server.listen(5)
        print ("[*] Listening on %s:%sd" % (local_host, local_port))
    except:
        print("[!!] Failed to listen on %s:%sd" % (local_host,local_port))
        print ("[!!] Check for others listening sockets or correct permissions")
        sys.exit(0)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        #print out the local connection information
        print ("[==>] Received incoming connection from %s:%sd" % (addr[0],addr[1]))

        #start a thread to talk to the remote host
        proxy_thread = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler,args=(client_socket,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first))

        proxy_thread.start()
    else:
        print ("something went wrong")

def main():
    #no fancy command-line parasing here
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) !=5:
        print ("Usage: ./TCP proxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] [remoteport] [receive_first]")
        print("Example: ./TCP proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.132.1 9000 True")

    #set up local listening parameters
    local_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])

    #set up remote target
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    #this tells proxy to connect and receive data before sending to remote host
    receive_first = sys.argv[5]

    if "True" in receive_first:
        receive_first = True
    else:
        receive_first = False

    #now spin up our listening socket
    server_loop(local_host,local_port,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first)

def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    #connect to the remote host
    remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect((remote_host,remote_port))

    #receive data from the remote end if necessary
    if receive_first:
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        hexdump(remote_buffer)

        #send it to the repsonse handler
        remote_buffer = respsonse_handler(remote_buffer)

        #if data is able to be sent to local client, send it
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print ("[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." % len(remote_buffer))
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)
    #now loop and read from local,sent to remote,send to local,rinse/wash/repeat
    while True:
        #read from local host
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)

        if len(local_buffer):
            print ("[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer))

            #send it to request handler
            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)

            #send data to remote host
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
            print ("[==>] Sent to remote.")

        #receive back response
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print ("[<==] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer))
            hexdump(remote_buffer)

            #send response to handler
            remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

            #send response to local socket
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

            print ("[<==] Sent to localhost.")

        #if no data left on either side, close connection
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print ("[*] No more data, closing connections.")

            break

#this is a pretty hex dumping function taken from the comments of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/142812-hex-dumper/
def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(src,unicode) else 2
    for i in xrange(0,len(src), length):
        s = src[i:i+length]
        hexa = b' '.join(["%0*X" % (digits, ord(x)) for x in s])
        text = b' '.join([x if 0x20 <= ord(x) < 0x7F else b'.' for x in s])
        result.append( b"%04X %-*s %s" % (i, length*(digits + 1), hexa, text) )
    print (b'/n'.join(result))

def receive_from(connection):
    buffer = ""

    #set a 2 second timeout; depending on your target this may need to be adjusted
    connection.settimeout(2)

    try:
        #keep reading the buffer until no more data is there or it times out
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(4096)

            if not data:
                break
            buffer += data
    except:
        pass
    return buffer

#modify any requested destined for the remote host
def request_handler(buffer):
    #perform packet modifications
    return buffer

#modify any responses destined for the local host
def response_handler(buffer):
    #perform packet modifications
    return buffer

main()
```

i have tried different ftp servers/sites,etc but get the same result, where am i going wrong with my code? any input or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

okay so turns out my script is good just the ftp servers i was running weren't haha
this is the final output:

```
anon@kali:~/Desktop/python scripts$ sudo python TCP\ proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftp.uconn.edu 21 True
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:21d
[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:51532d
0000 32 32 30 20 50 72 6F 46 54 50 44 20 31 2E 32 2E  2 2 0   P r o F T P D   1 . 2 ./n0010 31 30 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 28 66 74 70 2E 75  1 0   S e r v e r   ( f t p . u/n0020 63 6F 6E 6E 2E 65 64 75 29 20 5B 31 33 37 2E 39  c o n n . e d u )   [ 1 3 7 . 9/n0030 39 2E 32 36 2E 35 32 5D 0D 0A                    9 . 2 6 . 5 2 ] . .
[<==] Sending 58 bytes to localhost.
[==>] Received 353 bytes from localhost.
[==>] Sent to remote.
[<==] Received 337 bytes from remote.
```